# Difference between Google developers console vs Google Apps admin console

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

Can anybody please tell me what is the difference between creating consumer_id and consumer secret from Developers console vs creating them from the google apps admin console?

I have two Google accounts one for my personal activities (xxxx@gmail.com) and recently i purchased a Google apps account (xxxx@domainName.in).

When creating consumer_id and secret for service account ([link](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)) with xxxx@gmail.com:

```
client_id:  341552605300-d7nlrrrf4d4des778d4mm1lt5k4mesf1.apps.googleusercontent.com
Email Address: 341552605300-d7nlrrrf4d4des778d4mm1lt5k4mesf1@developer.gserviceaccount.com
client_secret: some long jumbled text in the downloaded JSON File
```

When creating with xxxx@domainName.in:

```
client_id: domainName.in

client_secret: Jxeosrrd1Rgz-dTJl2Pdsfds
```

I'm a newbie to oauth 2.0 and got confused why there is a difference in generation of consumer keys and secret between developers console and admin console